# Is there a way to run multiple requests concurrently and parallely in postman?

Tags: postman

I want to check if the receiving server can handle multiple requests sent to it at once.

Answer (score 0):

**newman command line utility is not designed for sending multiple request in parallel**,

**but you can use powershell** to try running collections multiple times.

```
$TargetPath=".\newman"
if (test-path ".\newman") {Remove-Item -r $TargetPath -Force}
New-Item -ItemType "directory" -path ".\newman\reports"
New-Item -ItemType "directory" -path ".\newman\logs"

For  ($i=0; $i -le 10; $i++) {
    $TestNewmanArgs="a.json -r cli,htmlextra --reporter-htmlextra-export newman\report-$i.html"
    $argz="run $TestNewmanArgs -k 
    "$i"
    Start-Process -FilePath "C:\Roaming\npm\newman" -ArgumentList $argz -PassThru
}
```

just store this as ps file and then right click and use run with powershell

this will execute newman in multiple cmd processes

**You can also use newmna as a nodejs library and write code to run the scripts in parallel**